# Loading svg assets with web pack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have the following weback loader:

```
loaders: [
    {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'}
]
```

I am storing all my svgs in a /res/ folder, but when I build my project I cannot access my resources with:

`<img src="img.svg" />`

What could be wrong with my loader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more detail, as to where that snippet of HTML is actually being used or how the rest of your webpack config is setup, my best guess is that you need to actually require the .svg file so that webpack will process it.

```
var svgImage = require('./img.svg');
/// svgImage can now be used in a template
```

When webpack runs your files through the are various loaders you have installed and will create a new file named to a hash: `img.svg -> {someHash}.svg`

This can be overridden in your webpack config.

```
{test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml&name=img-[hash:6].svg'}
```